# Angular2 - Issue with conditional attribute

Tags: angular

I am using the following to set a conditional attribute on the template :

```
<div [attr.dir]="rtlTextDirection"></div>
```

On the **.ts** I have

```
this.rtlTextDirection = 'rtl';
```

I expect to add it to the template like the following:

```
<div dir="rtl"></div>
```

However, it does not work for some reason...

Comment: We can't know either from this information.

Comment: Is that a correct implementation?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: It should also work without `attr.` because it's a global attribute.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer nice one ! I've just changed it to `[dir]="rtlTextDirection"` and it worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[dir](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir) is a global attribute that is available on all elements and reflected to the [dir](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dir) property.

Therefore just

```
<div [dir]="rtlTextDirection"></div>
```

should work